# HikariCP Wrapper (thread safety)

Tags: java, thread-safety, singleton, wrapper, hikaricp

I'm learning to use HikariCP (i'm new in java) and i found a wrapper but i think it's not thread safety, well the instance of the singleton is thread safety but not the method getConnection(). The class is this:

```
public class HikariCPWrapper{
    private static final HikariCPWrapper INSTANCE;
    private HikariDataSource ds;
    static  
    {  
    INSTANCE = new HikariCPWrapper();    
    }  

    private HikariCPWrapper(){
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig(); 
        //config.set... 
        //... 
        ds = new HikariDataSource(config);  

    }

    public static HikariCPWrapper getInstance ()  
    {  
        return INSTANCE;  
    }  

    public Connection getConnection()  throws SQLException  
    {  
        return ds.getConnection();  
    }  
}
```

Well, i've needed to send arguments to HikariConfig or HikariDataSource so I've re-write it this way:

```
public interface IConnectionProvider {
    void init(String jdbcUrl, String user, String password);
    Connection getConnection() throws SQLException;
}

    public class ConnectionProviderHikariCP implements IConnectionProvider{

    private static final ConnectionProviderHikariCP INSTANCE;
    private final HikariDataSource hikariDataSource;
    private Boolean initialized;
    //class initializer:
    static
    {
        INSTANCE = new ConnectionProviderHikariCP();
    }

    private ConnectionProviderHikariCP() {
        hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        initialized = false;
    }

    public static ConnectionProviderHikariCP getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(String jdbcUrl, String user, String password) {
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);        
        hikariDataSource.setUsername(user);
        hikariDataSource.setPassword(password);
        initialized = true;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        if(!initialized)
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Debe inicializar mediante el método Init() primero!!!!!."); 

        return hikariDataSource.getConnection();
    }

}
```

I use it this way:

```
IConnectionProvider connectionProvider = ConnectionProviderHikariCP.getInstance();
connectionProvider.init(url, user, passwd);

BaseDAOFactory fatory = new MySqlDAOFactory(connectionProvider);
IExerciseBO exerciseBO = new ExerciseBO(fatory);
```

But I'm not experienced in java so I need your advice. 
Is first class (the original) thread safety?
Is my implementation thread safety?

Comment: Everything is thread-safe. I would change the code to make it respect Java naming conventions, though: mathods start with a lower-case letter, variables don't contain underscores. getConnection() should not throw Exception, but SQLException. The try/catch in the static block is useless, since the constructor doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you. So then Can i skip put syncronized in methods init() and getConnection()? (I'll update the code with your recomendatios).

Comment: No. Removing them would make the code not thread-safe.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh I didn't understand your first comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HikariCP itself is thread-safe.  As I understand it, what you are trying to do is prevent callers to `getConnection()` before the `HikariDataSource` has been initialized via the `init()` method.  Presumably you also want to prevent multiple calls to `init()` the datasource.

Wrapping `getConnection()` with a synchronized is a bad idea in general with respect to pool throughput.  I recommend the following pattern, based on your code above:

```
public class ConnectionProviderHikariCP implements IConnectionProvider {

  private static final ConnectionProviderHikariCP INSTANCE;
  private final HikariDataSource hikariDataSource;
  private AtomicBoolean initialized;
  //class initializer:
  static
  {
     INSTANCE = new ConnectionProviderHikariCP();
  }

  private ConnectionProviderHikariCP() {
     hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
     initialized = new AtomicInteger();
  }

  public static ConnectionProviderHikariCP getInstance() {
     return INSTANCE;
  }

  @Override
  public void init(String jdbcUrl, String user, String password) {
     if (initialized.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);        
        hikariDataSource.setUsername(user);
        hikariDataSource.setPassword(password);
     }
     else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Connection provider already initialized.");
     }
  }

  @Override
  public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
     if (initialized.get()) {
        return hikariDataSource.getConnection();
     }

     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Debe inicializar mediante el método Init() primero!!!!!."); 
  }
}
```

Comment: "HikariCP itself is thread-safe." Where does this come from? If you are relying on an undocumented implementation detail please say so.