# What should the scope of a HikariDataSource object be?

Tags: java, hikaricp

I'm trying to use the HikariCP to pool my database connections. Reading through their documentations quickly, I'm not sure if I should keep my HikariDataSource object in memory and always ask from the exact same object for new connections or can I instantiate a new HikariDataSource object each time I want to create a new connection?

Answer (score 0):

It's preferred to create only one instance and use it for getting connection from pool using `getConnection()`, 
see also [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738151/hikaricp-wrapper-thread-safety) answer that uses HikariDataSource in a singleton pattern